# Is it thread-safe to replace a concurrent collection when there may be iterators?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been reading various things and it seems like this should work but I want to be sure. I have a static property that is supposed to be a cache (plus some other functionality related to the cache data). It stores the actual data in a ConcurrentBag, and it has an IEnumerable method to [filter and] yield return values from this bag. It updates itself like this:

```
ConcurrentBag<Foo> NewBag = GetNewThings();
Cache = NewBag;
```

From what I've read, it seems like this should work, though I didn't expect it to. I expected this to blow up any iterators that were reading when this happens. However I read that if another thread were iterating through the old list, it would finish on that instance of the list while the new list gets swapped. A second (new) thread would start on the new list, even while the old thread is still iterating through their old instance. This seems magic though, so I'm probably wrong, yes?

The other threads only iterate the list, the only writing happens here on these two lines.

Comment: Note that only tiny portion of "magic" is related to threading (the fact that pointer-sized assignments are atomic), the rest of behavior can easily be seen in single threaded synchronous code - changing value of variable holding the collection have no impact on collection itself nor its iterators.

Comment: Thread-safety is not a transitive property.  The fact that you cannot corrupt a ConcurrentBag by iterating it does *not* mean that *your* code is thread-safe.  It very rarely is, dealing with objects that are no longer in the bag or not seeing any that got added after you started iterating very rarely turns out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that if another thread were iterating through the old list, it
>   would finish on that instance of the list while the new list gets
>   swapped. A second (new) thread would start on the new list, even while
>   the old thread is still iterating through their old instance. This
>   seems magic though, so I'm probably wrong, yes?

What you read is correct.

This is thread-safe, but you might want to make the variable `volatile` or use `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` to ensure immediate visibility to all threads.

Comment: That answers another question I had re: volatile, which I also looked into. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The original instance assigned to `Cache` still exists, and that's the one the old thread is iterating over.

The new thread operates on the `GetNewThings()` result.