# C# Replace collection while enumerating

Tags: c#, multithreading

According to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327422/is-it-thread-safe-to-replace-a-concurrent-collection-when-there-may-be-iterators), somewhere, someplace on the internet it is verified that replacing some types of collections while enumerating them is possible/thread safe. 
<del>My tests below seem to confirm that.</del>

```
// This test confirmed insufficient by comments
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

Parallel.For(1, 10000, i => {
    foreach (var x in a)
        Console.WriteLine(i + x);
});
Parallel.For(1, 10000, i => a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

I would however very much like to read some official documentation or some concrete reference pertaining to this fact before i start implementing it in my code.
 
Can someone verify this/post a link?

Comment: The two Parallel.For are executed sequentially. Parallel.For only terminates when all the iterations are done. So you are not replacing a collection while enumerating it.

Comment: no collections are being iterated while being replaced in your test. The Parrallel.For does iteration 1 to 1000 concurrently and only returns when all 999 iterations have completed. foreach will totally hate you if you mess with "List<int> a" while it is iterating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, you are not in fact mutating `a` while you're iterating it.  You're iterating it a bunch, and then after you're done iterating it a bunch, you're mutating `a` a bunch, because `Parallel.For` will block until it has finished executing all of the iterations.

But, even if you *were* mutating `a` in parallel with the iterations here, it would in fact be perfectly safe.  The `foreach` is going to read the value of `a` **once** at the very start, get a reference to a list, and then from that point forward, *it's never going to look at `a` again*.  It's going to be working off of local copies to the reference to the list that it got from `a`, so it won't know or care what changes are made to the variable `a` after that point.  So if you're mutating what list `a` points to and also iterating `a` at the same time, then you don't know whether the list being iterated is what was in `a` before or after the change in another thread, but you know that the list being iterated *must* be one list or the other, and not some error or mix of the two.

Now if you were mutating *the list that `a` references* rather than mutating *the variable `a` to point to a new reference* then that would be entirely different.  `List` is not designed to be accessed from multiple threads at the same time, and so all sorts of bad things would happen.  If you used a collection specifically designed to be accessed from multiple threads, and you used it in a way it was designed to be used, then it could function properly.

Comment: I've been using concurrent dictionaries in cases where needed and called for. However for the current use case replacing the reference will be sufficient. Thanks alot for the explanation, i feel confident now implementing my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Servy's answer and what has been said in the comments, what you have isn't really an illustration of modifying the variable in parallel while iterating over it. Your `Parallel.For` loops run sequentially - i.e. first you iterate over the list 10000 times (*possibly* in parallel), **then** you replace it with a new list 10000 times (again, *possibly* in parallel).

```
// This doesn't modify or replace the collection at all, it just iterates over it a bunch of times
Parallel.For(1, 10000, i => {
    foreach (var x in a)
        Console.WriteLine(i + x);
});

// This happens AFTER the previous Parallel.For loop completes
// Thus, you're not actually iterating over the loop at this point, just replacing it a bunch of times
Parallel.For(1, 10000, i => a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Note that I said *possibly* in parallel - simply putting something in a `Parallel.For` loop doesn't guarantee that the framework will actually use multiple threads to accomplish the task, and you can't predict "in advance" how many threads it'll use if it does. Point being that this code doesn't even necessarily prove that these tasks are running on multiple threads (or how many they're running on if they are).

One other flaw in this test: you're replacing the class with the same exact collection every time, so you can't really tell which thread did the final update after the loop is done. Let's say that it uses 3 different threads to execute this - A, B, and C. How do you know which one made the last update to the collection? Recall that a `Parallel.For` loop is **not** guaranteed to execute sequentially, so it could have been updated by any of the three. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The syntax of a parallel loop is very similar to the for and foreach
>   loops you already know, but the parallel loop runs faster on a
>   computer that has available cores. **Another difference is that, unlike
>   a sequential loop, the order of execution isn't defined for a parallel
>   loop.** Steps often take place at the same time, in parallel. **Sometimes,
>   two steps take place in the opposite order than they would if the loop
>   were sequential.** The only guarantee is that all of the loop's
>   iterations will have run by the time the loop finishes.

Basically, then, with a Parallel.For loop you have no idea "in advance" the degree of parallelism, *whether* it uses parallelism at all, or even which order the steps will execute in (so using this construct necessarily entails giving up considerable control of how the code is actually executed).

Comment: The OP is mutating the variable holding the collection, not mutating the collection being iterated, so this doesn't apply to the situation.

Comment: @Servy Does my edit fix this? From my perspective, though, it doesn't really matter whether he's modifying the collection or not because he's not actually iterating over the list in the second loop.

Comment: The question is asking whether or not its safe to mutate the variable that is being iterated while the iteration is going on.  The question says nothing at all about mutating the collection while it is being iterated, so answering the later without answering the former isn't answering the question.  Nothing in the question mentions mutating the collection, it mentions replacing the collection with a new one, and you're not even discussing that.

Comment: `The .NET collection classes generally will not allow you to modify the collection while you're doing a foreach loop over them.` That is not something you can rely on.  If you make the modification *from the same thread doing the iterating* then sure, you can rely on that behavior, but if you're modifying it from another thread it could do any number of things, from throw various types of exceptions, to just producing the wrong value, to just not being observed.

Comment: @Servy Now I see your point, it would appear I misread the question - so the question is whether you can mutate the *variable*, not whether you can mutate the collection itself? That would make that part of my answer irrelevant... the OP's test of that idea's still invalid even for mutating the variable in my opinion though, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I said as much in my answer.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the clarification - I edited to remove the irrelevant parts, I just included my explanation of why the test doesn't work how the OP was thinking